# How is a list of elements added to the binary search tree diagram?

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree, diagram

I found a lot of source codes on how to add element to a binary search tree, but I wasn't able to find illustration of adding an element to a binary search tree in a diagram form.

For example if I was given: {55, 34, 54, 2, 78, 12, 9}

Can you please show me step-by-step how it's added to the BST?

```
               x

         b            y
      v     g      h     t
```

Like the tree diagram above. (It's just a tree example not sorted or anything)

Comment: What have you tried and why don't you use the number of elements, node positions etc to print out a certain number of spaces ?

Comment: please put your code here.

Comment: I was hoping to understand how elements are added to the Binary tree visually. I'm not interested in the code.

Comment: This may be of help: http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/mukundan/dsal/BSTNew.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple implementation (i.e not considering rebalancing the tree).

```
{34, 54, 2, 78, 12, 9}


         55 <-- root
```

You take the next element and compare it to the root. If it's greater, you add it to the right, otherwise to the left.

```
{54, 2, 78, 12, 9}


         55 <-- root
       /
     34
```

You do the same operation for the other elements recursively.

```
{2, 78, 12, 9}


         55 <-- root
       /
     34
       \
       54
```

---

```
{78, 12, 9}


          55 <-- root
        /
      34
     /  \
   2     54
```

---

```
{12, 9}


           55 <-- root
        /        \
      34         78
    /    \
   2      54
```

---

```
{9}


          55 <-- root
        /       \
     34         78
   /     \
  2      54
   \
    12
```

---

```
          55 <-- root
        /       \
     34         78
   /     \
  2      54
   \
    12
   /
  9
```

Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I was asking for.